# Print multiples of a number less than a given max

Tags: python

Print multiples of n that are less than m.

```
def print_multiples(n, max):
  while n <= max:
    a = range(n, (n*max)+1,n)
    print(*a)

print_multiples(4, 18)
```

so this example would only print

```
4
8
12
16
```

and each answer is on a new line.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your effort.

Comment: that is my code

Comment: And what problem do you run into?

Comment: What is your _specific_ question?

Comment: Why not just `print(*range(n, m, n))`? Note you shouldn't use `max` as a variable name as it overwrites the inbuilt `max()` function.

Comment: code doesn't work. If I take out the ```while loop```, I get ```4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, ...., 72```.(all the way to 72), since 4*18=72. So I need only multiples less than 18, and on a new line

Comment: that works @CDJB, with the less than m. Just need answers on a new line now.

Comment: for item in range ...: print(item)

Comment: I am guessing you don't need negatives

Comment: Based on @CDJB's solution: `print(*range(n, m, n), sep='\n')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do what you want. It divides the maximum number by the factor to get the maximum second factor (`//` rounds down) and then adds one because it is `range`. Then it will iterate through each of the second factors and print out the multiples.

```
def print_multiples(n, m):
  for x in range(1, m//n + 1):
    print(x*n)

print_multiples(4, 18)
```

Also, you should avoid using `max` as a variable name because it is a keyword for the `max()` function